# Algebra : Conjecture about basis for algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, nonassociative-algebras

Consider a non-associative commutative unital algebra of finite dimension such that elements are generated with real number coefficients
$(a_0, \dotsc, a_n) $
for a basis $\{1, i_1, \dotsc, i_n \}$.

If $a,b,c,d$ are invertible elements of the algebra then $ab = c$ and $ad = c$ implies $b = d$.
(cancellation property)

Assume the algebra is also power-associative and NOT nilpotent.

Can we always pick a basis, such that the multiplication table (for the basis elements) is a loop without having products equal to "sums ($+$)" of other basis elements ?